# Array and Linked Structures

Tags: java, arrays, element, structure

I am taking java data structures and algorithms class in school, and I am totally 
lost on Array and Linked Structures, and if someone could please tell me some
good links or tutorials that explains well...thanks

array operation:

- traversing
- resizing
- replacing an element
- replacing an element
  inserting an element
- deleting an element

linked structure characteristics:

- SLNode
- traversing
- replacing an element
- replacing an element
- inserting an element
- deleting an element

Comment: I dont have it , because it is sold out in bookstore, im waiting for it in mail, i ordered it on Amazon...

Comment: weird that you came here to ask people to do your homework :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get the big picute and understand the difference between those two.

As mentioned in [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> "An array is a container object that holds a fixed number of values of
>   a single type. The length of an array is established when the array is
>   created. After creation, its length is fixed".

In simply it means when you declare an array it should you should give a size.

If you think about the linked data structues you'll see they don't have predefinde size. Its like a chain. You can link new nodes to any where on the chain.
[Read this](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s2.html)

For manipulation of those read flowing articles.

- http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/10245
- http://www.roseindia.net/java/collection/array-operation-collections.shtml

There are many linked data structures, But first learn ArrayList it might easy for you

- http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_arraylist_example.xml
- http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/array_list_demo.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Arrays (VB and Java)
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164778(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164778%28v=office.10%29.aspx)
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/understanding-arrays-in-java.html

Linked Lists
http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_linklist.aspx
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/LinkedListBasics.pdf

Hope it helps!